# Why would a blaster dip crossblooded sorcerer instead of going sorcerer primary?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I saw this build that had 1 sorc crossblooded orc draconic 19 wizard admixture. Is this build still doable as primary sorc?  Can anyone tell me why people say to still go wizard? I'm not understanding.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4):

#### Because the Crossblooded archetype is *BAD* for primary sorcerers.

Sorcerers automatically get higher spell levels a level later than wizards do. This is a significant penalty, but it can be overcome. The crossblooded archetype causes a sorcerer to know one less spell of each spell level; since the first time you gain access to a new spell level you only know one spell of that level, crossblooded reduces you to knowing *zero* spells of that level. This effectively puts you at getting spells *two* levels later than a wizard would, which means you are *always* using spells that are a spell level lower than a wizard could use.

The build you're talking about is one level behind a single-classes wizard (since it has a one-level dip in sorcerer), but that's basically the same as being a *regular* sorcerer. It has the strong blaster benefits of being a crossblooded orc/draconic sorcerer without crossblooded's usual spell level penalty.

Essentially:

- full wizard = baseline
- normal sorcerer = full wizard - 1
- wizard with 1 level dip = full wizard - 1
- crossblooded sorcerer = full wizard - 2

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't prevent it from being 'doable', it is just a penalty that should be known. What is often overlooked is the limited spell list that a blaster actually cares about (you're already specializing, so spells beyond your core damage spells and survival spells are fluff).